# adding ULX function to a script

Tags: lua, garrys-mod

I need some help adding a Player:SetUserGroup to a separate script. Currently what I'm trying to do is once a "Test" is complete said user is to be whitelisted to a ulx group.

This is what it looks like so far. Any help would be greatly appreciated!!!

```
net.Receive("Player:SetUserGroup"), function(len, ply) 
if not IsValid(ply) or not ply:IsPlayer() then return end
if ply.ADLTable["GoodResponse"] >= (ADLTableCount*ADL.CompletePourcent)/100 then
Player:SetUserGroup( clonetrooper )

end
    end )
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to fix a few things: 1, net library uses callback as second argument, so the `)` should only be at the end of the block. And indentation is important...

```lua
net.Receive("Player:SetUserGroup", function(len, ply) 
    if not IsValid(ply) or not ply:IsPlayer() then return end
    
    if ply.ADLTable["GoodResponse"] >= (ADLTableCount*ADL.CompletePourcent)/100 then
        Player:SetUserGroup( clonetrooper )
    end
end )
```

Second: what is the content of the ADLTable attached to the player?
Third: You should use [ULIB (ulx uses it) to add users to usergroups.](https://ulyssesmod.net/docs/files/lua/ulib/server/ucl-lua.html#ucl.addUser)

```lua
ucl.addUser(    ply:SteamID64(),
nil,
nil,
"clonetrooper",
false)
```